# Get string length after it has changed but before its assigned

Tags: powershell

Lets say I want to do something like this:

```
$string = 'arbitrary string' # << is random
$string = ($string + 'randomstring').Substring(0, [math]::Min(20, $string.lenght) # < doesn't work properly
```

How do I get current length of `$string`, when it is not yet assigned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the string using `+=`.

```
$string = 'arbitrary string' # << is random
$string = ($string += 'randomstring').Substring(0, [math]::MIN(20, $string.Length)) #
```

Comment: Please don't change the question. If this question ins answered, accept it and start a new one.